# Line graph with asymmetric ribbon using Julia-Package "Plots"

Tags: plot, julia, gadfly, plots.jl

I figured out how to plot a line graph with an asymmetric "ribbon" around it with the package "Gadfly" and the following code

```
x=collect(-10:10);
y=[i^2 for i in -10:10];
ymin = y-5;
ymax = y+10;
using Gadfly
plot(x=x, y=y, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, Geom.smooth, Geom.ribbon)
```

(This was described in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966555/geom-ribbon-in-gadfly-julia-does-not-accept-int-vectors-as-input).)

[image]

Now i would like to do the same using the `plot` function of the "Plots" package. There are options `ribbon` and `fillrange` (see http://plots.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/pyplot/#layouts-margins-label-rotation-title-location) but I could not figure out how to use them. Is it possible to create such a plot using the "Plots" package and if yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until I tag a new version of RecipesBase and Plots, you'll need to:

```
Pkg.checkout("Plots")
Pkg.checkout("RecipesBase")
```

Now to reproduce your example, you could do:

```
using Plots; pyplot(border=false)
x = -10:10
y = x .^ 2
plot(x, y, ribbon=(5,10), fillalpha=0.2)
```

[image: plt]

The ribbon arg could take many forms:

```
plot(x, y, ribbon = 5)  # both sides are 5
plot(x, y, ribbon = 1:3) # both sides cycle through 1:3
plot(x, y, ribbon = (5, 1:3))  # bottom is 5, top cycles 1:3
```

Comment: I tried it with `Pkg.checkout`. With GR I get: "MethodError: convert has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Array{Float64,1})", `gadfly()` yields a deprecation warning. Also with `plotly()` it doesn't work ("fillrange ignored"). If it only works with PyPlot, then the "Plots" package is not the right choice for me at the moment. But anyway, thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: This currently works with pyplot and gr backends, with no need to Pkg.checkout.